# Create a directory with Google Drive API (Python)

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to create a folder in Google Drive with Python API. Here is the function I wrote

```
def testCreateDir(self):
    try:
        media_body = MediaFileUpload("ALLFS", mimetype='application/vnd.google-apps.folder', resumable=True)
        body = {
                'title': "ALLFS",
                'mimeType': "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
        }
        root_folder = self._service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()

        return root_folder['id']
    except errors.HttpError,error:
        print 'An error occured: %s' % error
        return None
```

Here is the Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "allfs/service/gdrive.py", line 63, in testCreatedir
    media_body = MediaFileUpload("ALLFS", mimetype='application/vnd.google-apps.folder',      
resumable=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 120, in  
positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/apiclient/http.py", line 419, in __init__
    fd = open(self._filename, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'ALLFS'
```

Everything else is working: read, write, search....Could anyone please help?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to insert any media body when creating a folder. Remove the line where you instantiate the MediaFileUpload and don't pass a media_body to the insert request.